# ¿Cual es el proceso en C++ para usar headers?

Tags: c++

Cual es el proceso en C++ para usar headers y despues crear un archivo de implementacion con el mismo nombre del archivo.h para las funciones?

Buenas, me gustaria saber cual seria el proceso detalladamente para poder realizar esto.

Comment: No existe un "proceso" específico para utilizar archivos cabecera, sólo crea tu archivo y luego en el código fuente asegurate de incluirlo si es necesario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#ifndef ALGO_H
#define ALGO_H
// Declaraciones
#endif // ALGO_H
```

En c++ todas las lineas que empiezan por # son instrucciones para el compilador, la primera linea usa un if para comprobar si ALGO_H a sido declarado si esto no a sucedio entonces procede con el codigo, en la siguiente linea se declara ALGO_H, de esta forma si algo.h se ejecuta de nuevo el codigo sera ignorado ya que ALGO_H ya a sido declarado.
Esto es así para evitar que funciones o todo lo que coloques ahí sea declarado mas de una vez.

Si te refieres a como declarar las funciones entonces:
algo.h

```
#ifndef ALGO_H
#define ALGO_H
typedef struct {
    char *name;
    char *value;
} Campo;

Campo *obtener_campos(int id);
int leer_entrada(char *nombre, char ciudad[256]);
#endif // ALGO_H
```

algo.cpp

```
#include "algo.h"
Campo *obtener_campos(int id)
{
//Funcion
}
int leer_entrada(char *nombre, char ciudad[256])
{
//Funcion
}
```

Como vez se declaran las funciones normalmente en el archivo cpp y el h se repiten la funciones con los mismos parámetros solo que no se implementan y se ponen los ; de final de linea.

Comment: Esta parte la entendi, pero lo que no entiendo es como poner las funciones en el header file y en el archivo de implementacion.cpp que se crea con el mismo nombre.

Comment: Gracias bro , ahora si me quedo claro